# PyFst Install Ubuntu Error Command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, ubuntu, openfst

With Python 2.7.12 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, I tried following instructions @ [PyFST Setup CMU](http://demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu/fa2014-11711/index.php/PyFST_Setup) to install OpenFst and pyfst but fails with error

> note:   candidate expects 16 arguments, 15 provided error: command
>   'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

and also tried @ [PyFST Setup OGI](http://www.csee.ogi.edu/~sproatr/Courses/TextNorm/tutorial.html) but fails with

`

> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Looks like OpenFst is setup properly because I am able to see fst commands.

```
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/demo/openfst-1.6.2$ ls ~/prefix/bin
```

> fstarcsort       fstencode        fstprune             fstsynchronize
>   fstclosure       fstepsnormalize  fstpush              fsttopsort
>   fstcompile       fstequal         fstrandgen           fstunion
>   fstcompose       fstequivalent    fstrelabel           pdtcompose
>   fstconcat        fstinfo          fstreplace           pdtexpand
>   fstconnect       fstintersect     fstreverse           pdtinfo
>   fstconvert       fstinvert        fstreweight          pdtreplace
>   fstdeterminize   fstmap           fstrmepsilon         pdtreverse
>   fstdifference    fstminimize      fstshortestdistance  pdtshortestpath
>   fstdisambiguate  fstprint         fstshortestpath fstdraw
>   fstproject       fstsymbols

However, I get this error when I try to run `sudo pip install pyfst`

...(only including a snippet of the error message because longer than the terminal window)

> /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h: In instantiation of ‘static
>   const fst::MinMaxWeightTpl& fst::MinMaxWeightTpl::NoWeight()
>   [with T = float]’:
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h:615:72:   required from ‘fst::MinMaxWeightTpl fst::Plus(const fst::MinMaxWeightTpl&,
>   const fst::MinMaxWeightTpl&) [with T = float]’
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h:621:28:   required from here
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h:576:69: error: ‘NumberBad’ is not a member of ‘fst::FloatLimits’
>            static const MinMaxWeightTpl no_weight(FloatLimits::NumberBad());
>                                                                            ^
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h: In instantiation of ‘static const fst::MinMaxWeightTpl& fst::MinMaxWeightTpl::NoWeight()
>   [with T = double]’:
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h:615:72:   required from ‘fst::MinMaxWeightTpl fst::Plus(const fst::MinMaxWeightTpl&,
>   const fst::MinMaxWeightTpl&) [with T = double]’
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h:626:29:   required from here
>       /usr/local/include/fst/float-weight.h:576:69: error: ‘NumberBad’ is not a member of ‘fst::FloatLimits’
>       error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-DngJ9w/pyfst/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-FFhvRI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DngJ9w/pyfst/

Or I try the following:

```
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/demo/openfst-1.6.2$ echo "export PREFIX=$(cd; pwd)/prefix" >> ~/.bashrc
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/demo/openfst-1.6.2$ 
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/demo/openfst-1.6.2$ echo 'export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$PREFIX/include:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
> export LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
> export LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/fst:$LIBRARY_PATH
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib/fst:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> export PATH=$PREFIX/bin:$PATH
> export PYTHONPATH=$PREFIX/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Which appears to work fine

```
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/demo/openfst-1.6.2$ echo $PREFIX
```

> /home/wilson/prefix

```
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/demo/openfst-1.6.2$ cd $PREFIX
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/prefix$ wget http://demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu/cdyer/pyfst-0.2.5.tar.gz
```

> --2017-05-21 18:37:34--  http://demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu/cdyer/pyfst-0.2.5.tar.gz Resolving
>   demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu (demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu)... 128.2.220.95 Connecting
>   to demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu (demo.clab.cs.cmu.edu)|128.2.220.95|:80...
>   connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length:
>   148781 (145K) [application/x-gzip] Saving to: ‘pyfst-0.2.5.tar.gz.1’
>
> pyfst-0.2.5.tar.gz. 100%[===================>] 145.29K   720KB/s    in
>   0.2s
>
> 2017-05-21 18:37:34 (720 KB/s) - ‘pyfst-0.2.5.tar.gz.1’ saved
>   [148781/148781]

```
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/prefix$ tar xzf pyfst-0.2.5.tar.gz
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/prefix$ cd pyfst-0.2.5/
wilson@wilson-300V3A-300V4A-300V5A:~/prefix/pyfst-0.2.5$ python setup.py
```

> install --prefix=$PREFIX running install running build running
>   build_py running build_ext building 'fst._fst' extension
>   x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall
>   -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c fst/_fst.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/fst/_fst.o -std=c++11 cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not
>   for C++ fst/_fst.cpp: In function ‘PyObject*
>   __pyx_pf_3fst_4_fst_12StdVectorFst_120draw(__pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_StdVectorFst*, __pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_SymbolTable*, __pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_SymbolTable*, __pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_SymbolTable*)’: fst/_fst.cpp:17681:191: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘fst::FstDrawer >
>
> > ::FstDrawer(fst::StdVectorFst&, fst::SymbolTable*&, fst::SymbolTable*&, fst::SymbolTable*&, int, std::__cxx11::string&,
> >     double, double, int, int, double, double, int, int, int)’  ble,
> >     __pyx_v_ssyms_table, 0, __pyx_t_5, 8.5, 11.0, 1, 0, 0.40, 0.25, 14, 5, 0);
> >                                                                                   ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/fst/script/draw.h:10:0,
> >                      from fst/_fst.cpp:242: /usr/local/include/fst/script/draw-impl.h:29:3: note: candidate:
> >     fst::FstDrawer::FstDrawer(const fst::Fst&, const
> >     fst::SymbolTable*, const fst::SymbolTable*, const fst::SymbolTable*,
> >     bool, const string&, float, float, bool, bool, float, float, int, int,
> >     const string&, bool) [with Arc =
> >     fst::ArcTpl >; std::__cxx11::string =
> >     std::__cxx11::basic_string]    FstDrawer(const Fst &fst,
> >     const SymbolTable *isyms,    ^
> >     /usr/local/include/fst/script/draw-impl.h:29:3: note:   candidate
> >     expects 16 arguments, 15 provided fst/_fst.cpp: In function ‘PyObject*
> >     __pyx_pf_3fst_4_fst_12LogVectorFst_120draw(__pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_LogVectorFst*, __pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_SymbolTable*, __pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_SymbolTable*, __pyx_obj_3fst_4_fst_SymbolTable*)’: fst/_fst.cpp:30639:191: error: no matching function for call to
> >     ‘fst::FstDrawer >
> >     ::FstDrawer(fst::VectorFst > >&, fst::SymbolTable*&, fst::SymbolTable*&, fst::SymbolTable*&, int,
> >     std::__cxx11::string&, double, double, int, int, double, double, int,
> >     int, int)’  ble, __pyx_v_ssyms_table, 0, __pyx_t_5, 8.5, 11.0, 1, 0,
> >     0.40, 0.25, 14, 5, 0);
> >                                                                                   ^ In file included from /usr/local/include/fst/script/draw.h:10:0,
> >                      from fst/_fst.cpp:242: /usr/local/include/fst/script/draw-impl.h:29:3: note: candidate:
> >     fst::FstDrawer::FstDrawer(const fst::Fst&, const
> >     fst::SymbolTable*, const fst::SymbolTable*, const fst::SymbolTable*,
> >     bool, const string&, float, float, bool, bool, float, float, int, int,
> >     const string&, bool) [with Arc = fst::ArcTpl
> >     ; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string]    FstDrawer(const Fst &fst, const SymbolTable *isyms,    ^
> >     /usr/local/include/fst/script/draw-impl.h:29:3: note:   candidate
> >     expects 16 arguments, 15 provided error: command
> >     'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Which version of python and ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Python 2.7.12 and Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: pyfst-0.2.5 is not maintained for couple of years. I suspect  the error is the result of the python interface code being out of sync with openfst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PyFST, it's out of date.  Python bindings are included with OpenFST since approximately version 1.5.1.  Just install OpenFST as normal, with the `--enable-python`:

```
./configure --enable-python
make
sudo make install
```

That should put the Python libraries in the appropriate places.

Some additional information is available [on the OpenFST website](http://www.openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/FST/PythonExtension).